# XmlDocument loading from file with non latin file path

Tags: c#, .net

I have instantiated XmlDocument and than trying to load XML file with non Latin symbols in the file pat. During loading the file I am facing with the

```
 ArgumentNullException
```

with message:

```
"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: str"
```

Stack Trace is -

```
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.HasIllegalCharacters(String[] str)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
at System.Uri.ParseConfigFile(String file, IdnScopeFromConfig& idnStateConfig, IriParsingFromConfig& iriParsingConfig)
at System.Uri.GetConfig(UriIdnScope& idnScope, Boolean& iriParsing)
at System.Uri.InitializeUriConfig()
at System.Uri.InitializeUri(ParsingError err, UriKind uriKind, UriFormatException& e)
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
at System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
at ....
```

There is a part of my code:

```
var xmlData = new XmlDocument();
if (File.Exists(xmlPath))
{        
    xmlData.Load(xmlPath);
    ...
}
```

xmlPath contain French letters.

What is wrong?
How I can open xml file with non latin characters?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `xmlPath` in the debugger? I think your code should work and I would bet that `xmlPath`does not hold the value you would expect.

Comment: xmlPath contains expected value. I want to add that before file loading I am verifying that file exist.

Comment: Please tell us what the value of `xmlPath` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution of the problem with using other class for data loading, like this:

```
var d = File.ReadAllText(xmlPath);
xmlData.LoadXml(d);
```

But question - "what is wrong?" still open.

Answer (score 0):

Load the file path into a uri first:

```
Uri xmlUri = new Uri(xmlPath);
xmlData.Load(xmlUri.AbsolutePath);
```